# Trying to replicate the Contact app's load thumbnail image animation

Tags: ios, ipad, contacts

In the Contacts app, when you choose an image for a contact, the thumbnail image is loaded into position with a cool animation. It happens right when the imagepicker dismisses.

If I had to guess, right when the imagepicker is dismissed, the image is put in a UIIMageView that matches the size and location of the cropped area of the imagepicker. Then the UIImageView is scaled down and into position. But it looks like it animates along a curve.

Is this how they did it? I'd like to implement something similar, but in an iPad app. If that was the case, I'd have to figure out the coordinates of image frame inside the popover.

Anyone have any idea how they did this? Am I on to something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a `CAAnimation` guy, but I imagine it's a combination of a `CAKeyframeAnimation` along a `UIBezierPath`, combined with a basic animation of the bounds. My bezier isn't quite right, but you probably get the idea. So, maybe it's something like:

```
CGPoint center      = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2.0, self.view.frame.size.height / 2.0);
CGRect  finalRect   = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 75.0, 75.0);
CGPoint finalCenter = CGPointMake(25.0, 25.0);

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:center];
[path addCurveToPoint:finalCenter
        controlPoint1:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 0.0) 
        controlPoint2:CGPointMake(100.0, finalCenter.y)];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YOURIMAGE.png"];
NSAssert(image, @"Error loading image");
CALayer *imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
imageLayer.contents = (id)image.CGImage;
imageLayer.bounds   = finalRect;
imageLayer.position = finalCenter;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:imageLayer];

CAKeyframeAnimation *animatePosition = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animatePosition.path = [path CGPath];
animatePosition.duration = 2.0;
[imageLayer addAnimation:animatePosition forKey:@"arc"];

CABasicAnimation *animateBounds = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds"];
animateBounds.duration = 2.0;
animateBounds.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:self.view.bounds];
animateBounds.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:finalRect];
[imageLayer addAnimation:animateBounds forKey:@"zoom"];
```

Comment: I believe there's also a scale animation, but what you have seems good.

Comment: @qegal Yeah, I was tempted by that, but I assumed the bounds of the final resting position would be critical (to fit into the desired final UI), so I thought that might be easier if RyeMAC3 animated the bounds. But I'm sure you could make scale animation work, too...

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'll have to play around with that. I never would have come up with that on my own!